# unity3d - how to create a terrain from a c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to create a piece of terrain in unity using only a script (c# preferably) to do this rather than the menu options on the editor. So far I only have this code below, but I don't know what to do next to get it to appear on the scene, can anyone help?

Thank you

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class terraintest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameObject terrain = new GameObject();
        TerrainData _terraindata = new TerrainData();
        terrain = Terrain.CreateTerrainGameObject(_terraindata);


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding :

```
Vector3 position = ... //the ingame position you want your terrain at
GameObject ingameTerrainGameObject = Instantiate(terrain, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

should make the terrain appear ingame. The Instantiate method returns a reference to the gameobject spawned ingame, so if you later want to access it, you can use that reference.